Lossy compression method: uint16 to a uint8?
I'm looking for suggestions on lossy data compression methods. I need to compress a uint16 to a uint8 such that the resolution loss increases with increasing uint16 values.  I am currently using the following:
def log2_compress(x: np.uint16) -> np.uint8:
    # Add l to avoid log2(0)
    y = math.log2(x + 1)
    # log2(1) = 0.
    # log2(65536) = 16.
    # Scale from [0,16] to [0,255].
    return np.uint8((y / 16) * 255)

This is simple but has the downside that it is wasteful on the uint8 side, namely
log2_compress(0) = 0
log2_compress(1) = 15
log2_compress(2) = 25

so [1,14], [16,24], etc. aren't used.  Can someone suggest a method similar to log2_compress but uses more (all?) of the uint8 bits? I am not really concerned about performance either.

Why is this tagged with Rust?

Prototyping in Python and ultimately implementing in Rust.  Tagging as Rust may be wrong here.  Removed.

Would math.floor(math.log(x)) (or math.ceil(math.log(x))) suffice? How slowly do you want the resolution loss to increase?

Also, does the output need to increase monotonically? Would it be OK if larger values of x could go back and "fill in" the gaps left by smaller values of x, e.g., log2_compress(60000) == 3)?

You might want to contrast your desired output with x % 256.

(or with x // 256)

@chepner - Regarding how rate of resolution loss, I'm not sure.  It is something I am actively looking into. Regarding, filling in gaps, that is probably fine.  The sqrt based compression is looking right now.

The best way to do this depends on why you're doing it.

Depending on what you mean by

such that the resolution loss increases with increasing uint16
values

you might want to try different compression functions. Without any further information about the context, we will assume that you are looking for an increasing concave function to map [0~65535] to [0~255].
You can try first the function sqrt:
def sqrt_compress(x: np.uint16) -> np.uint8:
    return np.uint8(math.sqrt(x))

If the smoothness of this function is not exactly what you need, you can try other powers rather that 1/2 for the square root. You can add the power as a parameter p that will have effect on the smoothness of the compression function:
def power_compress_p(x: np.uint16, p: float = 2) -> np.uint8:
    """Compression function. Higher value of p use less bits."""
    return np.uint8(2 ** (8 - 16 / p) * x ** (1 / p))

For your use case, use p > 1.
The power functions obviously are not the only compression that exist, you could use a dictionary to define a map function if you want better control over the granularity.

Thanks for the reply.  I am already looking at what you suggest (root_compress(x: np.uint16, n=2) -> np.uint8).  Square root seems to be the best for now.
